# My plugin keeps returning my command as a message

Tags: java, bukkit

Every time I run my command in-game it returns the command as a message. For example) I type "/heal" in-game, and it messages me "/heal" back.

My code

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String label, Strings [] args) {

    Player player = (Player) sender;

    if (cmd.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("heal")) {
        if (sender.hasPermission("city.heal")) {
            player.setHealth(20);
            player.setFoodLevel(20);
            sender.sendMessage("§fYou have been §bhealed §fand §bsated§f.");
            return true;
        }

        if (!sender.hasPermission("city.heal")) {
            sender.sendMessage("§cNo permission.");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

My plugin.yml

```
main: me.rarfiles.code.Code
name: Test
author: rarfiles
version: 1.0

commands:
  heal:
    usage: /<command>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have another piece of code elsewhere that is using that method? Because the're is nothing in the shown code that would even begin to message you back with the entered command. Are you also sure that the command is just not registering and you are seeing your own message?

Comment: I don't think there is anything interfering with it. This is a test plugin that I made for a heal command. Here is everything about the plugin: https://gyazo.com/1a21e0b85f39b54462e3a8610c7481d5

Comment: What does it look like when it 'messages you back'?

Comment: https://gyazo.com/04e6e50c803782d872b90bddf6a5814e

Comment: I think it's something to do with the `usage:` part. Something is causing that to trigger, as the game doesn't think you are using the command correctly. I can't work out however, why may this be the case.

Comment: Does it even run the heal? If not, something is cancelling the chat event. (Another plugin?)